# Parametrized query inside mysqli class

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using Mertol Kasanan's class for running parametrized queries -

http://liveplanet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r132/trunk/db/DB.php

I am very satisfied with the script except for some issues that I don't seem to put my finger on.
As it states in the brief tutorial in the class's description the method for running the query is:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ? AND user_type = ? LIMIT ?',$id,$user_type,$limit);
```

Can anybody figure out how to run a query without defining any parameter as it seems that

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = 'y' ");
```

neither

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = 'y' ", '');
```

do not  do the trick as it returns a binding error;
A workaround would be

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 1 = ? AND id = 'y' ", 1);
```

Is there a neater way to run my query?
I don't need parameters as the query gets it's values from a safe source inside a class.

Edit:

Let's say I have this:

```
if($HC == 'C'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `photo_c` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s AND cat != 'D' GROUP BY pic  LIMIT ?";
       $query = $this->dbs->query($sql,$this->user,$this->user_head,4);
    $results = $this->dbs->numRows($query);                 
    if($results < 3){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s ORDER BY  id ASC LIMIT ?";
       $query = $this->dbs->query($sql, $this->user,$this->user_head,4);                                
                                    }
    }else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `photo_c` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s AND cat = ?s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";
    $query = $this->dbs->query($sql,$this->user,$this->user_head,$HC,4);
        $results = $this->dbs->numRows($query);
                    }
```

Now, in order to get the data from the right query I can either define $data->getAll under each query - but that would mean repeating my code or I could try extracting the data from the last defined $query result - which I do not know how to do.
I know that there may be a better way of doing this but I am trying to improve my coding style as I think the safemysql class would need some improvements even if that would mean a bit more documentation.
I could try using $db->getAll instead of $db->query but, as far as I know, I cannot use numRows on GetAll.

Comment: The only thing you need for this edited question is PHP function count()

Comment: I posted the code. However, it can be improved, once I get the meaning of it. Looks like you want conditional query building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this class is totally unusable. And the problem you mentioned is a least one.
It seems that someone  who wrote it, never used this class in a real life project.

So, if you want a class which works and works way better, go for [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), as it will do exactly what you want:

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE status = 'y'");
```

(note that you've got your data already, without any further code)

Nevertheless, you have to understand that the following statement of yours

> I don't need parameters as the query gets it's values from a safe source inside a class.

is wrong.
It's OK to use a hard-coded value as you wrote it, but if you were intended to use a "safe" *variable* - it ought to be added via placeholder. Otherwise your query remains error-prone and unsafe.

So, it have to be

```
$id = 1; // "safe" variable
$data = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ?i", $id);
```

To answer edited question. Not sure if it's what you need, but here is the code. It wu

```
if($HC == 'C')
{
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM `photo_c` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s AND cat != 'D' GROUP BY pic  LIMIT ?";
    $data = $this->dbs->getAll($sql,$this->user,$this->user_head,4);
    if (count($data) < 3) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s ORDER BY  id ASC LIMIT ?";
        $data = $this->dbs->query($sql, $this->user,$this->user_head,4);
    }
} else {
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM `photo_c` WHERE `user` = ?i AND `pic` != ?s AND cat = ?s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";
    $data = $this->dbs->query($sql,$this->user,$this->user_head,$HC,4);
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the suggestion. You were right advising me not to use that class - it seems it has problems working on php 5.4.  I have i small problem though as it seems the small documentation for safemysql doesn't cover: how to num rows?

Comment: There is a numRows() function as well.

Comment: Not to straight forward;   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = ?i,'1'");   /   $results = $db->numRows($query);  How else can I use $query data. Can I use it to extract the $rows?

Comment: If you need all rows at once (like in most web applications you do), just use `$data = $db->getAll()` instead of `query()`. You will have all your rows already in `$data` array

Comment: Look, you can count returned rows using PHP function count(). I don't entirely get the meaning of your code but I'll post how it can be

Comment: I just gave up on using count after finding out how to use numRows. I'll consider usging it back again. Isn't' it a way that you could do something like this?  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=?i,'1');  Then use whatever method necessary: query,getRow,getAll, etc.?  Thanks and sorry for this. I am implementing as I have to make the transition to php 5.4

Comment: I can't get the meaning of this code. May be you'd better write me to email, you'll find it in my profile.